# Data change updating at random - Vue/Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a 'watched-items' feature: click on the icon, it adds to an array in my Vuex store, the icon changes to a tick, click on the tick, it removes it from the Vuex store and the icon changes back.

When I check Vuex in dev tools it's working as it's supposed to.

The strange thing is the data property responsible for switching out the icons only sets to `false` when it wants to. It will work for a short period, across refreshes, then will stop for no apparent reason and won't come back until it feels like it.

Example (apologies for the quality): [image: gif demonstrating the issue]

In the console you can see the data property 'watched' switches to true but only switches to false when it feels like it. Any ideas why it's doing this?

'Watched' icons:

```
<img
  src="svg/eye-regular.svg"
  v-if="!watched"
  @click="addToWatched(item), isWatched(item), log()"
/>
<img
  src="check-solid.svg"
  v-if="watched"
  @click="removeFromWatched(item), isWatched(item), log()"
/>
```

('item' is an object being passed as a prop)

`watched` data property:

```
data() {
  return {
    watched: false
  };
},
```

computed:

```
...mapGetters(["watchedItems"])
```

methods:

```
...mapActions([
  "addToWatched",
  "removeFromWatched"
]),

isWatched(item) {
  let watchFind = this.watchedItems.find(i => {
    return i.id === item.id
           ? (this.watched = true)
           : (this.watched = false);
  });
},

log() {
  console.log("data -> watched", this.watched);
}
```

Vuex store (not sure this code is relevant as the store seems to work fine):

```
const actions = {
    // commit items to watched
    addToWatched({ commit }, item) {
        commit("setWatchedItems", item);
    },
    removeFromWatched({ commit }, item) {
        commit("deleteWatchedItem", item);
    },
};

const mutations = {
    setWatchedItems: (state, item) => {
        let watchFind = state.watched.find(i => {
            return i.id === item.id;
        });

        if (!watchFind) {
            state.watched.push(item);
        }
    },
    deleteWatchedItem: (state, item) => {
        let watchFind = state.watched.find(i => {
            return i.id === item.id;
        });

        if (watchFind) {
            state.watched = state.watched.filter(i => {
                return i.id !== item.id;
            });
        }
    },
};

const state = {
    watched: []
};

const getters = {
    watchedItems: state => state.watched
};
```

**UPDATE**

It's still acting as described above, but, I've found that if I add to 'watched' on one item then immediately after remove from 'watched' on another, it works:

[image: update gif demonstrating issue]

(You can't see when I click but at the start of the gif I'm clicking the same icon repeatedly with no change)

Comment: the event handlers should be separated by `;` like `@click="addToWatched(item);isWatched(item);log()"`

Comment: It's now working! Hopefully it stays that way. Thank you @BoussadjraBrahim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced the data and method with a computed property and it seems as though it's fixed the issue.

```
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["watchedItems"]),
        watched: function() {
            return this.watchedItems.find(i => {
                return i.id === this.item.id ? true : false;
            });
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

the event handlers should be separated by `;` like :

```
<img
  src="svg/eye-regular.svg"
  v-if="!watched"
  @click="addToWatched(item); isWatched(item); log()"
/>
<img
  src="check-solid.svg"
  v-if="watched"
  @click="removeFromWatched(item); isWatched(item); log()"
/>
```

Comment: what's the new issue?

Comment: It seems if I click to add the item to 'watched' and then click another, already 'watched', item to remove it, it works no problem. But just clicking as normal on the same item the ```watched``` property gets stuck on ```true```.

Comment: It's like it can't handle more than one click or it breaks

Comment: did you try `i.id === item.id
           ? (this.watched = !this.watched)
           : (this.watched = false);`

Comment: I've changed it to that and it's still working. Could change at any minute but I'll have to wait and see I think.

Comment: could you create a codepen or a fiddle in order to debug it and know the exact issue?

Comment: I tried making a fiddle but I don't know how to use Vuex with it. I'll have another go soon and update the post